# Definition of simple function : in $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\boldsymbol 1_{A_i}$ does the $A_i$'s needs to have finite measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In my lecture and in the book *Real analysis* of Stein and Shakarchi, they define simple function in $(X,\mathcal X,\mu)$ as $$\varphi (x)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\boldsymbol 1_{A_i}(x),$$
where $A_i$ are measurable with finite measure.

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) they don't require the $A_i$ to have finite measure. Is it a mistake from them or the definition of simple function doesn't require the $A_i$ to have finite measure ?

If it doesn't require to be finite, can it be a problem to define integral for simple function ? Indeed, as far as I know, you defined the integral of a simple function as $$\int \varphi =\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mu(A_i),$$
(it can possibly be $\infty $). But how could we define the integral of $\boldsymbol 1_{[0,\infty )}-\boldsymbol 1_{(-\infty ,0)}$ ?

Comment: This depends on who you ask.  Stein and Shakarchi do require $A_i$ finite, but I believe Folland's "Real Analysis" does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a problem with wikipedia's definition, whereas I do see one with yours, if applied to spaces which are not $\sigma$-finite.

The correct set-up in a measure space $(X,\mathcal E,\mu)$ should be the following (which, as far as I'm concerned, is more or less taken from chapter 11 in *Real Analysis* by Royden):

- a real-valued function is simple if and only if the following equivalent conditions hold:

  1. the range of $f$ is finite and $f$ is measurable
  2. there are $E_1,\cdots, E_k\in\mathcal E$ and $a_1,\cdots, a_k\in\Bbb R$ such that $f=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i1_{E_i}$
- for measurable $g:X\to \Bbb R$ such that $g\ge 0$, $$\int_{X} g\,d\mu:=\sup\left\{\sum_{a\in \operatorname{range} \phi} a\mu\left(\phi^{-1}\{a\}\right)\,:\, \phi\text{ simple }\land 0\le\phi\le g\right\}$$
  where implicitly $\infty+\text{nonnegative stuff}=\infty$.
- for generic measurable $g:X\to \Bbb R$,  $$\int_X g\,d\mu:=\int_X g^+\,d\mu-\int_X g^-\,d\mu$$
  whenever at least one of the terms in the RHS is finite.

You can make the intermediate step of defining $\int_X\phi\,d\mu$ for non-negative simple functions (and prove afterwards that it coincides with the other one).

Notice that taking the least upper bound over simple functions with support of possibly infinite measure is not an issue, because if there is one such funcion satisfying $0\le \phi\le g$, the by all means $\int_X g\,d\mu$ must be $\infty$.

A reason why you should consider simple functions with support of infinite measure is that, while such an assumption is irrelevant in the $\sigma$-finite case, in a more general set-up you might run into pathologies. For instance, consider the measure space $(X,\mathcal E,\mu)$, $X=\{x,y\}$, $\mathcal E=\mathscr P(X)$, $$\mu(\emptyset)=0\\ \mu\{x\}=1\\ \mu\{y\}=\infty\\ \mu(X)=\infty$$

Then, what's $\int_X1\,d\mu$? By my definition, it's indeed $\infty$, because $0\le\phi=1_X\le1$. However, if you include in the $\sup$ just the $\phi$-s that can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i1_{E_i}$ for positive $a_i$ and $E_i$-s of finite measure, then $\int_X1\,d\mu=1\ne \mu(X)$ !

Comment: Why is it a problem for non $\sigma -$finite space ? Take $\mathbb R$ with the measure that gives the cardinality of a set, then simple function are linear combianison of caracteristic function of finite set... in what is this a problem ?

Comment: @user659895 I don't think there is an issue with the counting measure on $\Bbb R$ specifically, because sets of infinite measure *do* contain subsets of arbitrarily large measure there (while still not being $\sigma$-finite because some subsets aren't *covered* by any countable sequence of subsets of finite measure). At least, I'm not seeing one right now. The issue might come out when you have subsets that do not have subsets of arbitrarily large finite measure. Such is the one I've described, where the single point $y$ weights $\infty$.

Comment: Indeed, good point. Do you know the book "real-analysis" by Stein and shakarshi ? (it's very famous), if you see in the chapter 6, they really define simple function as linear combinaison of characteristic function of sets with finite measure... strange, no ?

Comment: No, I never had the pleasure. I confirm that *Real Analysis* by Royden does as I've said, though.

Comment: Since the book explains Lebesgue integration twice (once in ch.4 for $\Bbb R$ and once in ch.11 for general measure spaces), Royden also leaves a short note on why in the general case it isn't good to consider just the simple functions that vanish outside a set of finite measure.

Comment: Nice example.  Measures that can have infinite-measure sets without also having arbitrarily large but finite-measure subsets seem pretty pathological, though.

Comment: @JairTaylor I've just come up with one. And in "pathological cases" you want the right definition (because then it might not make them pathological).

Comment: @Gae.S. Of course, I didn't say they didn't exist.  But I wouldn't feel too bad in excluding such cases or having counterintuitive results there. Unless there are cases where such measures are useful to have around - which is possible.

Comment: I don't quite get why you would want sporadic Fatou-like inequalities $\int 1_A\,d\mu<\mu(A)$ for the sake of excluding some special instances during the process of defining as a $\sup$ of stuff an operator that you *expect* to be monotone.